# How do I figure out the size of specific RDDs in the cache?

Tags: apache-spark

I am frequently dealing with containers getting killed by YARN for exceeding memory limits. I suspect it has to do with caching/unpersisting RDDS/Dataframes in an inefficient manner.

What is the best way to debug this type of issue?

I have looked at the "Storage" tab in the Spark Web UI, but the "RDD Names" don't get any more descriptive than "MapPartitionsRDD" or "UnionRDD". How do I figure out which specific RDDs take up the most space in the cache?

In order to figure out the Out of Memory errors, I will need to figure out which RDDs are taking up the most space in the cache. I also want to be able to track when they get unpersisted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the `RDDs` you can set meaningful names using `setName` method:

  ```
  val rdd: RDD[T] = ???
  rdd.setName("foo")
  ```
- For `catalog` backed tables:

  ```
  val df: DataFrame = ???
  df.createOrReplaceTempView("foo")
  spark.catalog.cacheTable("foo")
  ```

  the name in the catalog will be reflected in both UI and `SparkContext.getPersistentRDD`.
- I am not aware of any solution which works for standalone `Datasets`.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a good way to figure out when the RDDs are unpersisted? Or do you basically have to keep refreshing the page?